# DomDocument возвращает текст в виде кодов символов

Tags: php, кодировка

```
$dom->saveHTML()
```

Функция возвращает русский текст в виде кодов символов:

```
<p>&#1063;&#1090;&#1086;...
```

Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обязательно в HTML вставляйте

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
```

указав при этом вашу кодировку (если она отличается от UTF-8).

Обратите внимание, что аналог из синтаксиса HTML5 (`<meta charset="utf8">`) не сработает.